# [Power Automate - Http Response Task]Outlook Adaptive Card "CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY" doesn't update if task is configured to Asynchronous

Tags: outlook, office365, powerapps, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have a power automate flow which updates the outlook adaptive card based on the approval.

[image]

After **"Submit"** it should be:
[image]

**However, this stopped working after I updated the configuration of power automate HTTP response task to aysnchronous.**

FYI - Asynchronous was used to handle multiple requests in a sequence intentionally.

Parallelism was set to 1 in "HTTP Trigger"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not sure why adaptive card is not refreshing even after the submit.

Please help me out. Thanks